# Why does this hash calculating bit hack work?

Tags: rust, bit-manipulation

For practice I've implemented the [qoi specification](https://qoiformat.org/qoi-specification.pdf) in rust. In it there is a small hash function to store recently used pixels:

> index_position = (r * 3 + g * 5 + b * 7 + a * 11) % 64

where r, g, b, and a are the red, green, blue and alpha channels respectively.

I assume this works as a hash because it creates a unique prime factorization for the numbers with the mod to limit the number of bytes. Anyways I implemented it naively in my code.

While looking at other implementations I came across this bit hack to optimize the hash calculation:

```rust
fn hash(rgba:[u8:4]) -> u8 {
        let v = u32::from_ne_bytes(rgba);
        let s = (((v as u64) << 32) | (v as u64)) & 0xFF00FF0000FF00FF;

        s.wrapping_mul(0x030007000005000Bu64.to_le()).swap_bytes() as u8 & 63
    }
```

I think I understand most of what's going on but I'm confused about the magic number (the multiplicand). To my understanding it should be flipped. As a step by step example:

1. `let rgba = [0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]`.
2. On my machine (little endian) this gives `v` the value `0x78563412`.
3. The bit shifting spreads the values, giving `s = 0x7800340000560012`.
4. Now here's where I get confused. The magic number has the values that should be multiplied aligned in a 64 bit field (3, 5, 7, 11), spaced the same way that the original values are. However they seem to be in reverse order from the values:

```
0x7800340000560012
0x030007000005000B
```

When multiplying it would seem that the highest value, the alpha channel (0x78), is being multiplied by 3, while the lowest value, the red channel (0x12), is being multiplied by 11. I'm also not entirely sure why this multiplication works anyway, after multiplying the values by various powers of 2.

I understand that the bytes are then swapped to big endian and trimmed, but that's not until after the multiplication step which loses me.

I know that the code produces the correct hash, but I don't understand why that's the case. Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm surprised at the `from_ne_bytes`. Shouldn't it be `from_le_bytes`? Otherwise the bytes _won't_ be flipped on big endian CPUs, leading to an incorrect result…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think about the way the math works, you *want* this flipped order, because it means all the results from each of the "logical" multiplications cluster in the *same* byte. The highest byte in the first value multiplied by the lowest byte in the second produces a result in the highest byte. The lowest byte in the first value's product with the highest byte in the second value produces a result *in the same highest byte*, and the same goes for the intermediate bytes.

Yes, the `0x78...` and `0x03...` are also multiplied by each other, but they overflow *way* past the top of the value and are lost. Having the order "backwards" means the result of the multiplications we care about all ends up summed in the uppermost byte (the total shift of the results we want is always 56 bits, because the 56th bit offset value is multiplied by the 0th, the 40th by the 16th, the 16th by the 40th, and the 0th by the 56th), with the rest of the multiplications we *don't* want having their results either overflow (and being lost) or appearing in lower bytes (which we ignore). If you flipped the bytes in the second value, the `0x78 * 0x0B` (alpha value & multiplier) component would be lost to overflow, while the `0x12 * 0x03` (red value & multiplier) component wouldn't reach the target byte (every component we cared about would end up somewhat that wasn't the uppermost byte).

For a possibly more intuitive example, imagine doing the same work, but where all the bytes of one input except a single component are zero. If you multiply:

```
0x7800000000000000 * 0x030007000005000B
```

the logical result is:

```
0x1680348000258052800000000000000
```

but removing the overflow reduces that to:

```
0x2800000000000000
//^^ result we care about (actual product of 0x78 and 0x0B is 0x528, but only keeping low byte)
```

Similarly,

```
0x0000340000000000 * 0x030007000005000B
```

produces:

```
0x9c016c000104023c0000000000
```

overflowing to:

```
0x04023c0000000000
//^^ result we care about (actual product of 0x34 and 0x5 was 0x104, but only 04 kept)
```

In that case, the other multiplications did leave data in result (not all overflowed), but since we only look at the high byte, the rest gets ignored.

If you keep doing this math step by step and adding the results, you'll find that the high byte ends up the correct answer to the four individual multiplications you expected (mod 256); flip the order, and it won't work out that way.

The advantage to putting all the results in that high byte is that it allows you to use `swap_bytes` to move it cheaply to the low byte, and read the value directly (no need to even mask it on many architectures).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Is there a name for this particular modulo trick? I guess I'm mostly wondering what the constraints on this are. Will this work for any value packing or is there a minimum required "space" between values?

Comment: @Laharah: I don't know of a general term for the principle; tricks like this are frequently used in [the various Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), which is where I first became familiar with them. There's definitely a minimum spacing (you don't want any products being output to the second highest byte for instance, because the overflow would spill into the high byte and corrupt your result; similarly, you have to be careful with the byte below that because too many products summing there could also carry up), but I don't have an equation to hand you.

Comment: @Laharah: Note that this case *does* produce values in that third highest byte, but the fixed multipliers are low enough and sparse enough you never need to worry about it; this does imply that adding too many more multipliers, or using larger multipliers, could create a problem.